# JavaSCript Selecting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

```
     <select>
<script type="text/javascript">     
    $.get(     
      'http://www.ufilme.ro/api/load/maron_online/470',     
      function(data){     
        var mydata = new Array();     
        var i = 0; // индекс массива материалов
        $('name', data).each(function(){     
          if($(this).text()=='MATERIAL_ID') mydata[i++] = new Array(); // массив материалов
          mydata[i-1][$(this).text()] = $(this).next().text();     
        });
        var htm = '';
      for(i in mydata) htm += "<option value=\"" + mydata[i]['TITLE'] + "\">"
    + mydata[i]['TITLE'] + "</option>";
        $('#real').html(htm);
      },     
      'xml'     
    );
</script>
</select>
```

ok problem 1 resolved now i want it to da like a selection .. and i added  but it does not have any effect

Comment: You have your quotes all mixed up

Comment: please don't forget to mention your framework when you're using one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because it's not valid syntax, specifically the `option value`, but also `+''"`  You're missing quotes.

```
htm += "<option value=\"" + mydata[i]['TITLE'] + "\">"
    + mydata[i]['TITLE'] + "</option>";
```

Comment: cool it worked now i have a problem i added `<select></select>` tags before and after javascript but it does not have any effect do you have any other ideas

Comment: @VicToRSava .. Looks like you are not appending it anywhere in your DOM

Comment: i edited the main post , so i want it to look something like `<select>options..</select>` and i aded select tags before and after javascript code .. but it didnt worked